# a while loop for input validation c++

Tags: c++, loops, validation, for-loop, while-loop

I'm writing a program with a set number of choices to select from (a, b, and c), but for some reason my `while` loop is not working the way I want it to. I want to only accept lowercase 'a' 'b' or 'c', and uppercase 'A' 'B' or 'C'. I'm pretty sure the way I'm doing it is incorrect. I'm in "Intro to Comp Sci", if that helps understand where I'm at.

Here's my code for what I have right now:

```cpp
while (choice == 'a' && choice == 'A' || choice == 'b' && choice =='B' || choice == 'c' && choice == 'C'){
    cout << "We dont offer that package. Please try again:\n ";
    cin >> choice;
    //cin.clear();
    //cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: How can that condition match? How can choice ever be more than one thing simultaneously? Think it through logically. It's not really a programming problem even.

Comment: I think you should have a conversation with your teacher to gain more clarity on the assignment and on the topic. That's what they're there for :)

Comment: Your condition says that `choice` must be equal to `'a'` and `'A'` ***at the same time***. That's not possible.

Comment: Consider this: The operator && has higher precedence than the operator ||. So, your condition is equivalent to `(choice == 'a' && choice == 'A') || (choice == 'b' && choice == 'B') || (choice == 'c' && choice == 'C')`. Can this ever be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is logic. If I'm not incorrect you want to ask for input until their input is one of A a B b C c?

Putting your while loop into words your saying:
while choice is A and a
or choice is B and b
or choice is C and c
Putting it that way it obviously can't work because how can choice be A and a?

What you want is to loop until choice is one of A a B b C c

Your return also shouldn't be in the while loop, I am assuming you want to return the choice they made after it is valid?

I also added the ! (this is "not", this inverts the result of a condtion - turns true into false, and false into true) operator before all of your conditions as without this you would be looping while choice is correct which means that it would continue only after an incorrect choice is entered.

In short, this code loops through asking for an input until the user's input is one of A a B b C c, after which it returns the input they gave.

```
while (!(choice == 'a' || choice == 'A' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'B' || choice == 'c' || choice == 'C')) {
    std::cout << "We dont offer that package. Please try again:\n ";
    std::cin >> choice;
}
return choice;
```

In english this is while choice isn't A or a or B or b or C or c then ask for input

Comment: yeah thanks it works no.i knew i was getting the logic mixed up

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow

You want that any one of a, A, b, B, c, C as valid. So you need to modify your code as follows:

`while (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A' || choice == 'b' || choice =='B' || choice == 'c' || choice == 'C')`

Also, you have written:

`return choice;`

This will immediately terminate the loop and return from current function which contains this while loop.

Comment: i swear i had this

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, glad you joined the coding train, so you want to only accept characters, but not any, just (a,b,c,A,B,C), that's cool so you made the first steps that were creating a never ending loop but our condition should be something false when the variable choice is not in the upper list. So we want something like

```
if((choice != 'a') && (choice != 'b') && (choice != 'c') && (choice != 'A') && (choice != 'B') && (choice != 'C'))
{
    //Stay in the loop
}
```

so we can write this in the while loop as follows:

```
while((choice != 'a') && (choice != 'b') && (choice != 'c') && (choice != 'A') && (choice != 'B') && (choice != 'C'))
```

Thus the full code would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice;
    cin >> choice;
    while((choice != 'a') && (choice != 'b') && (choice != 'c') && (choice != 'A') && (choice != 'B') && (choice != 'C'))
    {
        cout << "Sorry this package isn\'t offered by us, try something else: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    cout << "Your choice was " << choice << endl << "So you chose one of the following (a,b,c,A,B,C)";

    return 0;
}
```